# Extracting a password protected .7z file with 'p7zip' returns an error

Tags: extract, 7zip

I am trying to extract a password protected .7z file with `p7zip -d filename.7z` command. Unlike on Windows, on Ubuntu I do not get a prompt to enter password. Instead the terminal throws an **E_NOTIMPL** error. Could it be that the file is corrupted? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Wonderful!  I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [known bug/limitation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/p7zip/+bug/122935) in `p7zip`, in which it cannot work with password-protected encrypted files (technically by design as a 'lighter' kind of 7zip), and throws the error you've stated here when it tries to work with them.

The correct approach for encrypted/passwords 7z files is to use `p7zip-full` instead of `p7zip`, which should then work as it should.